# Implementing add for reference of type

Tags: rust, reference, operators, addition

I'm trying to implement the add method for a struct that contains an array.
I want to implement the method for generic types that implement AddAssign for their respective references.
The following code doesn't complile

```
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Test<T> {
    data: [T; 2]
}

impl<T> Add<&Test<T>> for Test<T> where T: AddAssign<&T> {
    type Output = Test<T>;

    fn add(mut self, rhs: &Test<T>) -> Self::Output {
        self.data.iter_mut().zip(rhs.data.iter()).for_each(|(r, l)| {
            *r += l;
        });
        self
    }
}
```

and gives the error:

```
impl<T> Add<&Test<T>> for Test<T> where T: AddAssign<&T> {
   |                                                      ^ explicit lifetime name needed here
```

But defining a lifetime just gives other errors. I can solve this by dereferecing but that's not what I want since I believe it will lead to unnecessary copying. Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifetime needs to be used for all the references present (both the impl definition and the rhs reference).  The following code will compile for me:

```
impl<'a, T> Add<&'a Test<T>> for Test<T> where T: AddAssign<&'a T> {
    type Output = Test<T>;

    fn add(mut self, rhs: &'a Test<T>) -> Self::Output {
        self.data.iter_mut().zip(rhs.data.iter()).for_each(|(r, l)| {
            *r += l;
        });
        self
    }
}
```